# Best Way to Populate Visualforce Picklists of Countries and States?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dependent-picklist, selectlist, country-and-state

I am currently making a `Visualforce Page` for registration and I have both `Country` and `State` fields (both picklist) to populate. I have looked for resources online and I found out some possible solutions:

1. Salesforce Data Management -> State and Country/Territory Picklists
2. Using `countries.js` ([Generic Country & State Dropdown List – countries.js](http://www.cssscript.com/generic-country-state-dropdown-list-countries-js/))
3. Manually coding it using an `Apex Controller`.

What would be the best approach to populate those picklists options?

Comment: You can use anyone of the three. It really doesn't matter that much. All of them should work for you.

Comment: If you want to use the same data across application, in multiple objects, I would suggest you can go for **Global Picklists**.

Comment: You don't need to put `Q>` in your question titles. We can tell it's a question. :)

Comment: @San Tosh, Is it easy to implement Global Picklists considering the State picklist is dependent on the Country picklist?

Comment: @Lance Shi...considering the state will be depending on the value of country, I think its possible through apex controller but it would take much time and code. I haven't tried Country and State picklist yet and I'm currently using countries.js but I keep having js errors when using it with salesforce.

Comment: What error do you get for using countries.js?

Comment: @Lance Shi.
---
Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
---
line : countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','-1');

Comment: Well, I would suggest you debug into your chrome(or your browser's) developer tool and look into why countryElement is undefined. I believe there is something wrong with the way you use the library